# unable change privacy setings for mobile phone property

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

I am trying to change the privacy settings for the mobile phone through central administration, however the option is dimmed. I though that as with any other option this could changed.

I have tried both in "user properties" or "user policies" of the user profile service application, but both are dimmed. any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing. This appears to be by design. I think you may beable to change it with PowerShell, but do so at your own risk...there is probably a dependancy on this property, like Search.

Comment: Mathew, my users dont want to share their mobile phone number with everyone on the company. I think this makes sense? Looking at how well designed the "my site" is, this detail was certainly overlooked.. Thank you.